# Largest positive finite IEEE number in terms of n and e?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee

Hi I'm doing homework for my computer science class and I'm stuck on this question.

Given a IEEE floating-point format of n bits with e exponent bits, give expressions for

- a)The largest finite positive number.
- b)The largest (closest to 0) negative number.
- c)The minimum ULP.

in terms of n and e.

Could somebody help with these and explain why? Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can meet you halfway if you show some effort towards answering the questions :)

Comment: well I understand how you imput in each a number for each (Ex 7 , 8) so the first 7 bits are specified for the number and the second for exponent. But Im just confused how I can leave it in terms of e and n

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia [Basic formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats) table helpful. Think about what "E max" and the "Digits" would be for your format. The largest finite positive number has exponent E max and ones in all available significand bits. For part b, you need to consider the subnormal format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers can be expressed as

```
(-1)^Sign * Number * 2 ^ Exponent
```

And usually you have 23 bits for the number, 8 for the exponent and 1 for sign. With that you could answer 1) and 2). I don't know what ULP is.

Comment: [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)  24 bits for the number (23 explicitly store, 1 implied).

Comment: “ULP” stands for “Unit in the Last Place” and is the difference between two consecutive floating-point numbers. It varies with the actual floating-point number whose difference with its successor we are talking about, and “the smallest ULP”, if such a notion makes sense, is technically the same as the smallest positive floating-point number (which is a denormal).

Answer (score 0):

in `C` you can just ask for this kind of informations to the appropriate header, in this case [`float.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%lf \n", FLT_MAX);
    return (0);
}
```

for more you simply pick the right macro from the documentation that I just linked.

Answer (score 0):

a)The largest finite positive number.

Sign +
 N bits 1.111...1111
 e exponent bits: 111....110 - bias   (pattern 111....111 reserved for INF and NaN)
 bias: typically 1/2 of e or  011...111

+1.1111111.... * power(2, 111...110 - bias)
 ~ +1.0 * power(2, 111...111 - bias)
 ~ +1.0 * power(2, 100...000)
 ~ power(2, power(2,e-1))

b)The largest (closest to 0) negative number.

Sign -
 N bits 0.000...001
 e exponent bits: 000....000 - (bias-1)  (min exponent has -1 bias)
 bias: typically 1/2 way 011...111

-0.000...001 * power(2, 000...000 - (bias-1))
 -0.000...001 * power(2, 000...000 - (bias-1))
 -1.0 * power(2, -N - (bias-1))
 -1.0 * power(2, -N - (bias-1))
  -power(2, power(2,-N - (power(2,e-1)-1-1)))

c)The minimum ULP.

Unit in the last place

`+` version of answer in b.